# Installing bitcoind as a dependency on travis-ci

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu

I'm trying to install bitcoind as a dependency on travis-ci. Here is my `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: scala
scala: 
  - 2.11.7

notifications:
  on_success: change
  on_failure: change

before_install:
  - sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin -y
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install bitcoind -y

apt_packages:
  - bitcoind

before_script:
  - mkdir -p /home/travis/.bitcoin && cp bitcoin.conf /home/travis/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
  - dpkg -L bitcoind 
  - /usr/bin/bitcoind -regtest -daemon

script: "sbt clean coverage test"
after_success: "sbt coverageReport coveralls"
```

and here is a link to the build failure:

https://travis-ci.org/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s-rpc-client/builds/236451398

notice that `dpkg -L` returns the following

```
$ dpkg -L bitcoind

/.

/usr

/usr/share

/usr/share/doc

/usr/share/doc/bitcoind

/usr/share/doc/bitcoind/examples

/usr/share/doc/bitcoind/examples/bitcoin.conf.gz

/usr/share/doc/bitcoind/copyright

/usr/share/doc/bitcoind/changelog.Debian.gz

/usr/share/lintian

/usr/share/lintian/overrides

/usr/share/lintian/overrides/bitcoind

/usr/share/man

/usr/share/man/man1

/usr/share/man/man1/bitcoin-cli.1.gz

/usr/share/man/man1/bitcoind.1.gz

/usr/share/man/man5

/usr/share/man/man5/bitcoin.conf.5.gz

0.00s$ /usr/bin/bitcoind -regtest -daemon

/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 54: /usr/bin/bitcoind: No such file or directory
```

There isn't anything installed in /bin/. Any suggestions?

Note: If I just specify `bitcoind` instead of `/usr/bin/bitcoind` I get the same problem

https://travis-ci.org/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s-rpc-client/builds/236438191

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Precise is no longer supported by the Bitcoin PPA team, as the listing showed the .deb package contains no binary. The package description says:

> Bitcoin dummy package - please upgrade to a newer distro for an
>   up-to-date Bitcoin package.
>
> Due to change in Bitcoin Core 0.13.0, we can no longer reasonably ship
>   Bitcoin Core for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. You can either upgrade Ubuntu or
>   download the statically-linked Bitcoin Core binaries from bitcoin.org

[On the PPA mirror](http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bitcoin/) you can see that Trusty (14.04 LTS), Xenial (16.04 LTS), Yakkety (16.10) and Zesty (17.04) are all supported (they have reasonable file sizes). I'd recommend going with Xenial as that has LTS (Long Term Support).

The other option - as the description says - is downloading the binary from the [official bitcoin site](https://bitcoin.org/), unzipping it and using that instead. For the current version:

```
wget https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.14.2/bitcoin-0.14.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
cat bitcoin-0.14.2-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz| gzip -d | tar -xv
./bitcoin-0.14.2/bin/bitcoind
```